# Haskell Programming Assignment, "Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[a0] -> Int’ "and a few more Errors

Tags: haskell

The assignment I have: A function numOccurences that takes a value and a list, returning the number of times that value appears in the list. I am learning haskell and am getting frustrated, this is my code for this:

```
numOccurences:: b -> [a] -> Int
numOccurences n [ls]
  |([ls] !! n==True) =  (numOccurences(n (tail [ls])))+1
  |otherwise = 0
```

The errors I am getting are as follows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI7Rm.jpg

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add the error messages as text, and not as an image -- it makes things easier for everyone.

Comment: This function is a good example of a fold! `numOccurrences n xs = foldr (\x i -> if x==n then 1+i else i) 0 xs`

Comment: Taking a list argument as `[xs]` is one of the most frequent mistakes I see here on SO. I have no idea what course / book / tutorial is prodding beginners towards it. It is not an habit inherited from other programming languages. Yet, somehow beginners assume that they must name their list parameters as `[xs]`, as if `xs` were too simple to be correct ("it is a list, not a single argument" or some similar bogus argument?). Whatever is teaching this, it is causing a lot of harm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few pointers:

First, in your type signature, using different type variables (i.e. `b` and `a`) creates the possibility that you could look for occurrences of a value of one type, in a list with another type, which in this case is not what you want. So instead of two type variables, you just want to use one.

Second, whatever the concrete type of your list is, whether it's `[Char]`, `[Int]`, etc., it needs to be equatable (i.e. it needs to derive the `Eq` typeclass), so it makes sense to use the class constraint `(Eq a) =>` in your type signature.

Third, since we're traversing a list, let's use [pattern matching](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching) to safely break off the first element of the list for comparison, and let's also add a base case (i.e. what we do with an empty list), since we're using recursion, and we only want the recursive pattern to match as long as there are elements in our list.

Lastly, try to avoid using indexing (i.e. `!!`), where you can avoid it, and use pattern matching instead, as it's safer and easier to reason about.

Here's how your modified function might look, based on the above pointers:

```
numOccurences :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Int
numOccurences _ [] = 0
numOccurences n (x:xs)
  | n == x    = 1 + numOccurences n xs
  | otherwise = numOccurences n xs
```

Comment: so the => does what?  and thank you so much! you helped me so much! simple errors from staring at it for to long haha :)

Comment: The `=>` symbol allows us to make our type variable `a` an instance of the `Eq` typeclass. Members of the `Eq` type class can be equated (e.g. `'a' == 'a'`, `2 /= 3`).